# Is it "Olympic-size pool" or "Olympic-sized pool"?

Tags: grammar

Is it "Olympic-size pool" or "Olympic-sized pool" (with a 'd')? Is one correct and the other wrong and if so, why? Or are both correct?

Comment: Use [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams) to find out which is more common.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=olympic-sized%20pool%2Colympic-size%20pool&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Colympic%20-%20sized%20pool%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Colympic%20-%20size%20pool%3B%2Cc0) *olympic-size* is about 50% more common these days. But until the mid-70's, they were almost equal. But both are used enough that I think either could be considered correct.

Comment: I think you are right, and I'm undoubtedly revealing my age by suggesting this, but I still feel that "sized" is correct and that "size" has come into use primarily as a lazy use of the language (and not just when referring to swimming pools, of course). As an editor, I would change "size" to "sized" unless the author had a compelling reason not to, such as quoting a source who used "size."

Comment: @MarkHubbard There are other, similar phrases: bite-size, fun-size. The first is about equal in both forms, the second is only used without the "d".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [*Olympic-size pool*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic-size_swimming_pool) has a wikipedia article, where "olympic sized pool" appears in an image caption in the same article.  It a quick Google search shows plenty of uses of both.